# Double quote in command as variable in a bash

Tags: bash, arguments, quotes, xmlstarlet

I am trying to make a variable the xmlstarlet command which includes arguments:

```
WARNING=$(xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u "'"/programs/program/log/@level"'" -v 4 ${FILE})
```

Unfortunately, without the double quote or single quote even the xmlstarlet does not accept/see the element.

Any help to include quote(s) as output in the command would be welcome :)

Thank you.
AL.

Comment: Have you tried using escape character? say `\'/programs/program/log/@level\'`

Comment: ++ xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u /programs/program/log/@level -v 4 ./file.xml
+ BMWARNING=
+ '[' -z --info ']'
+ case ${1} in

Comment: Eh? You shouldn't be putting a literal quote in there at all. That's not correct XMLStarlet usage.

Comment: That said, `ed --inplace` doesn't print anything on stdout, it just edits the file in-place, so why would you expect it to put anything into the `WARNING` variable at all?

Comment: As I am trying to update the xml based on argument into a bash.

Comment: Then why capture the stdout of the command into a variable? If anything, you'd want to capture only its stderr.

Comment: To be clear, when I say you shouldn't be using literal quotes, that's assuming the difference between literal and syntactic quotes is understood. In your working example, you're passing only syntactic quotes -- meaning that only the contents of that quoted string, but not the quotes themselves, are passed to the program being run.

Comment: ...and to document my claim that all-caps variable names are reserved: See fourth paragraph of POSIX spec @  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

**The claim that literal quotes are needed in this expression for XMLStarlet to find your desired element is false**.

Rather, you're running an *in-place edit* command, when capturing stdout only makes sense in the context of a *select* command (or a conventional edit with replacement text sent to stdout); for an in-place edit, stdout will be empty.

If your goal is to capture stderr associated with the in-place edit operation:

```
warnings=$(xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u "/programs/program/log/@level" -v 4 "$file" 2>&1)
```

...will copy stderr to stdout, ensuring that it is captured.

---

That said, if your goal in capturing `warnings` is to check for success, don't rely on looking at stderr; instead, check exit status:

```
if warnings=$(xmlstarlet ed --inplace ... 2>&1); then
  echo "Update succeeded" >&2
else
  echo "Update failed: $warnings" >&2
fi
```

Comment: As when I run the command, the element is correctly found: xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u "/programs/program/log/@level" -v 4 file.xml

Comment: @user4711416, those quotes are syntactic, not literal; they're consumed by the shell, not sent to XMLStarlet.

Comment: @user4711416, ...however, when you put `'"'` around a double quote, you made it literal, meaning it's sent to XMLStarlet, meaning its contents are parsed as an XPath string rather than an expression.

Comment: @user4711416, ...if `xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u "/programs/program/log/@level" -v 4 file.xml` works, then `xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u /programs/program/log/@level -v 4 file.xml` would work just as well, in this specific case where your XPath contains no whitespace or other characters which the shell would parse as syntax.

Comment: I have moved show the "warnings" to each case usage and it works out. somehow these could not be defined at the early stage of the script. Thank you Charles for your suggestions which I used :)

Comment: If you were to ask a question that included a reproducer for that behavior, I'll hazard we could work out why. (Might be something like http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024, for instance).